# Is there any way to create an Excel file and save it or e-mail it?

Tags: ssis

Is there any way using SSIS (or any other MSSQL Server features) to automatically run a stored procedure and have the output saved as an Excel file (or even a flat file) and then have that newly created file sent to people via e-mail?
Sorry, I'm a complete newbie to SSIS.

Comment: Stored procedure runs - what does it do? Does it output the data as a recordset, load a table (which then needs to be queries to create the extract), something else? But yes, quite doable - decompose your problem into smaller steps (SSIS export data to file (or to excel), send email SSIS) and use your favorite search engine with those terms. Otherwise, we're going to need more information to help you identify the best approach and implementation

Comment: thanks for the reply buddy :) so my stored procedure returns a table, this is pretty much a chunk of a larger table. all the stored procedure does is to filter the table with only "today's" data, with getdate(). so the step 1 is to run the stored procedure and retrieve the table. step 2 will be exporting the table to an Excel spreadsheet, step 3 is emailing it. im quite a newbie with SSIS, so any chance you could kindly guide me through please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In broad strokes, you'll have an SSIS package with 2 tasks and 3 connection manager.

The first task is a Data Flow Task. Much as the name implies, the data is going to flow here - in your case, from SQL Server to Excel.

In the Data Flow task, add an OLE DB Source to the data flow. It will ask what Connection Manager to use and you'll create a new one pointed at your source system. Change the source from the Table Selector to a Query and then reference your stored procedure `EXECUTE dbo.ExportDaily'`

Hopefully, the procedure is nothing more than `select col1, col2, colN from table where colDate = cast(getdate() as date)`  Otherwise, you might run into challenges for the component to determine the source metadata. Metadata is the name of the game in an SSIS data flow. If you have trouble, the resolution is version dependent - pre 2012 you'd have a null operation select as your starting point. 2012+ you use the WITH RESULT_SETS to describe the output shape.

With our source settled, we need to land that data somewhere and you've indicated Excel. Drag an Excel destination onto the canvas and again, this is going to need a connection manager so let it create one after you define where the data should land. *Where* you land the data is important. On your machine, C:\user\pmaj\Documents is a valid path, but when this runs on a server as ServerUser1... Not so much. I have a pattern of C:\ssisdata\SubjectArea\Input & Output & Archive folders.

Click into the Columns tab, and there's nothing to do here as it auto-mapped source columns to the destination. Sort the target column names by clicking on the header. A good practice is to scroll through the listing and look for anything that is unmapped.

Run the package and confirm that we have a new file generated and it has data. Close Excel and run it again. It should have clobbered the file we made. If it errors (and you don't have your "finger" on the file by having it open in Excel, then you need to find the setting in the Excel destination that says overwrite existing file)

You've now solved the exporting data to Excel task. Now you want to share your newfound wisdom with someone else and you want to use email to do so.

There are two ways of sending email. The most common will be the Email task. You'll need to establish a connection to your SMTP server and I find this tends to be more difficult in the cloud based world - especially with authentication and this thing running as an unattended job.

At this point, I'm assuming you've got a valid SMTP connection manager established. The Send Email Task is straightfoward. Define who is receiving the email, the subject, body and then add your attachment.

An alternative to the Send Mail Task, is to use an Execute SQL Task. The DBAs likely already have sp_send_dbmail configured on your server as they want the server to alert them when bad things happen. Sending your files through that process is easier as someone else has already solved the hard problems of smtp connections, permissions, etc.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'TheDbasToldMeWhatThisIs'
,   @recipients ='pmaj@a.com;billinkc@b.com'
,   @subject = 'Daily excel'
,   @body = 'Read this and do something'
,   @file_attachments = 'C:\ssisdata\daily\daily.xlsx';
```

Besides using existing and maintained mechanism for mailing the files, Execute SQL Task is easily parameterized with the `?` place holder so if you need to change profile as the package is deployed through dev/uat/prod, you can create SSIS Variables and Parameters and map values into the procedure's parameters and configure those values post deployment.

Comment: sorry i could not reply earlier to this, was because i was doing something entirely different.

Comment: im having some problem setting up the "Excel Destination". I can choose an empty file, but i only have 3 options in regards to "Data Access Mode"; 1.Table or View - which does not work if i click New (simply closes off the dialog window) and trying to look into the dropdown under "Name of the Excel sheet:" which causes an error "Could not retrieve the table information". 2. "Table name or view name variable" has an empty dropdown with no buttons to do anything. 3. "SQL Command", which i can not understand what SQL Command has to do with Excel file. any chance you could help me there please?